# Error al cambiar nombre del paquete

Tags: java, android, android-studio

me pasa algo muy extraño. Me pasaron una plantilla de una app. Cuando la pruebo por USB me funciona correcto. Pero cuando le cambio el nombre del paquete, se instala en el dispositivo, se intenta abrir, pero se cierra, se crashea. El caso es que sólo me pasa en algunos teléfonos, en concreto lo he probado con Xiaomi Note 5 y el Note 7 con Android 9. En otros dispositivos no hay ese problema. Y si subo la app a la tienda de Google Play igual no se inicia en estos teléfonos.
Por ahí sale en rojo estos errores:

```
 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tblDictionary
```

Sí, usa SQLite, pero igual no entiendo porque falla solo cambiando el nombre de paquete

```
    *E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.desarrollador.nombreprueba, PID: 815
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:240)
        at com.dictonary.template.MainActivity$getList.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:395)
        at com.dictonary.template.MainActivity$getList.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:323)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.*
```

Por favor, una ayudita. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

se debe a que no estas definiendo un `mensaje` al escribir en el LogCat mediante

```
Log.i(TAG, `texto`);
```

El error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tblDictionary

Se debe simplemente que no existe una tabla a la cual haces referencia, si funcionaba correctamente y cambiaste el `package name`, te sugiero elimines caché o la aplicación y la subas nuevamente para que se genera la estructura de la base de datos con sus respectivas tablas.

**Lo que sucede en este caso es que la base de datos se crea dentro un directorio que tiene la estructura que es precisamente el nombre del `package name`, si lo cambias  ya no encontrará la bd o sus elementos.**